# How do I group by two fields and return the original objects that match?

Tags: linq, group-by

Can anyone tell me what I'm messing in either of these attempts to locate a duplicate first and last name via Linq?

// Attempt 1

```
var  duplicateName =  
    from o in people
    from x in people 
    group o by new { Last= x.LastName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant(),  First=x.FirstName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant() }
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

// Attempt 2

```
var  duplicateName =  
        people.GroupBy(x => new { Last= x.LastName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant(),  First=x.FirstName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant() })
        .Where(g=> g.Count() > 1) 
        .Select(y => y)
        .ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second attempt is nearly what you want. But you select the groupings. If you want to select the objects in the groupings, you should use `SelectMany`:

```
var  duplicateName =  
        people.GroupBy(x => new { Last= x.LastName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant(),  First=x.FirstName?.Trim()?.ToUpperInvariant() })
        .Where(g=> g.Count() > 1) 
        .SelectMany(y => y)
        .ToList() ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm running into an issue where everything is "flat", I need to Linq to group the similar objects together, with some partitioning (the groupBy parameter)

Comment: But then the grouping is exactly what you need. The similar objects are grouped under a Key. You could use something like `.Select(y => new { y.Key, Duplicates = y.Select(p => p) }`.

Comment: Ah, the y.Select(p => p) concept eluded me!